# How do I add async attribute for scripts?

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript, overrides, header

I would like to add `async` to script tags coming from here `<jdoc:include type="head"  />`.

I have done some research and I found a few solutions, however those are for custom scripts.

I managed to find a workaround by editing the core file `HeadRenderer.php` located in `[root]/libraries\src\Document\Renderer\Html` and directly adding the `async` attribute, but It doesn't feel quite right.

Is it possible to add `async` and `media="all` for Joomla core scripts and css, such as `templates/system/css/general.css`and `media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js?06b66bce294749c101f79cb21aac7ace`?

So my question is:

Is there any way to either override the head core file or adding `async` from my `index.php` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better not edit ("core hack") Joomla's core files because that's a recipe for disaster.

The `async` attribute is available if you use the `HTMLHelper` to include your CSS file. See Joomla 3.9.19 /libraries/src/HTML/HTMLHelper.php line 687 for how to write a `<link>` element to load a CSS file and it's documentation.

```
// Namespace to include HTMLHelper
use Joomla\CMS\HTML\HTMLHelper;

// Add the template.css stylesheet to the <head>
HTMLHelper::_(
    'stylesheet',
    'template.css',
    ['version' => 'auto', 'relative' => true],
    ['async' => 'async']
);
```

Comment: And for JavaScript check the same file a few lines down (line 665) for the HTMLHelper `script` method.

Comment: Just an FYI that the `async` attribute doesn't do anything on a `<link>` element, which `HTMLHelper::_('stylesheet'...);` generates. However it will work on `<script>`. In Joomla 3, you're going to have to override the Styles Renderer to preload CSS files or create a plugin

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too, thank you. I need for both to be honest. I'm trying `onload("this.media='all'")` for `<link>`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add attributes to all scripts, use a system plugin with `onBeforeCompileHead` event.

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;

class PlgSystemExample extends CMSPlugin
{
    protected $app;

    public function onBeforeCompileHead()
    {
        foreach ($this->app->getDocument()->_scripts as &$script)
        {
            $script['async'] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

> Is there any way to either override the head core file or adding async from my index.php file?

Although similar code can be added to the template file, it will not affect modules because they are rendered after the template has been parsed. As well as some plugins which add assets during `onBeforeRender` or `onBeforeCompileHead` events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will keep that in mind. For now Peter's solution fits better in my case but your answer is also helpful.

Comment: By the way, I also used your solution. By adding: `foreach($this->app->getDocument()...` and it's worked out. Thank you once again.